# Can this Scala code snippet be made more concise?

Tags: scala

I've seen this Scala code snippet somewhere:

```
def toSentiment(sentiment: Int): Sentiment = sentiment match {
    case x if x == 0 || x == 1 => Sentiment.NEGATIVE
    case 2 => Sentiment.NEUTRAL
    case x if x == 3 || x == 4 => Sentiment.POSITIVE
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite the `case` statement more concisely? I suspect there must be a simpler (shorter) way to express `x if x == 0 || x == 1` condition.

By the way, this form:

```
def toSentiment(sentiment: Int): Sentiment = sentiment match {
    case 0 => Sentiment.NEGATIVE
    case 1 => Sentiment.NEGATIVE
    case 2 => Sentiment.NEUTRAL
    case 3 => Sentiment.POSITIVE
    case 4 => Sentiment.POSITIVE
}
```

is not what I'm looking for. I'm hoping for something like this:

```
def toSentiment(sentiment: Int): Sentiment = sentiment match {
    case x in {0, 1} => Sentiment.NEGATIVE
    case 2 => Sentiment.NEUTRAL
    case x in {3, 4} => Sentiment.POSITIVE
}
```

or even:

```
def toSentiment(sentiment: Int): Sentiment = sentiment match {
    case 0, 1 => Sentiment.NEGATIVE
    case 2    => Sentiment.NEUTRAL
    case 3, 4 => Sentiment.POSITIVE
}
```

Comment: That is already concise, you mean explicit :D

Comment: It"s a very interesting question Paul, but I think you might get better answer to it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mathemats I edited my question with a few forms I was looking (hoping) for. BTW, I just noticed Gilad's answer, which is exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
def toSentiment(sentiment: Int): Sentiment = sentiment match {
    case 0 | 1 ⇒ Sentiment.NEGATIVE
    case 2     ⇒ Sentiment.NEUTRAL
    case 3 | 4 ⇒ Sentiment.POSITIVE
}
```

Note that this match is not exhaustive. You could get a runtime error if you run, for example: `toSentiment(5)`. Some linters would warn you about this. A safer version (assumming any other number would be neutral) could be:

```
def toSentiment(sentiment: Int): Sentiment = sentiment match {
    case 0 | 1 ⇒ Sentiment.NEGATIVE
    case 3 | 4 ⇒ Sentiment.POSITIVE
    case _     ⇒ Sentiment.NEUTRAL   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: sure, np :) BTW, it may be an overkill for this simple use case, but you may find [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) helpful for more complicated numeric range checks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
def toSentiment(sentiment:Int): Sentiment = {
  import Sentiment._
  Vector(NEGATIVE,NEGATIVE,NEUTRAL,POSITIVE,POSITIVE)(sentiment)
}
```

which occupies less characters, but which I do not think is better.

I would: check the range of `sentiment`, which could make this function, and the original one, throw an exception if it were 6, for example.

Using `import Sentiment._` can save you some verbosity.